# Mapbox allow user to click on map and pin?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

As the question says I want to allow users to click on the map and add a pin, I need to do that in order to display to users where is the business located and because I don't know the location. I need to allow them to insert it. However, documentation is a bit confusing for me and either I cannot find it or I just missed it.

So far I have:

```
   <div id="right" class="map">
        <div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
        <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGl2ZS1vbGRoYW0iLCJhIjoiY2ozbXk5ZDJ4MDAwYjMybzFsdnZwNXlmbyJ9.VGDuuC92nvPbJo-qvhryQg';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
        });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a marker using the mapbox gl js API.

Example is already there:

https://www.mapbox.com/blog/custom-markers-mapboxgl/

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/

If you want to add the marker on a clicked position you could use something like this:

```js
map.on('click', (e) => {
    var coords = `lat: ${e.lngLat.lat} <br> lng: ${e.lngLat.lng}`;

    // create the popup
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setText(coords);

    // create DOM element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id = 'marker';

    // create the marker
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .setPopup(popup)
        .addTo(map);
  });
```

```css
.mapboxgl-marker {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #305bad;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. He's asking about clicking the map in an open area (without markers) to add a "pin" to that lat lng.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event handler to the map surface. In the handler, add a layer with your "pin". In the example below, I added a circle layer but you could just as easily add a symbol layer for a custom "pin".

```
        self.map.on("click", function(e){
            console.log("background click", e.lngLat);
            var geojson = {
                type: "FeatureCollection",
                features: [{
                    type:"Feature",
                    geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat ]}
                }]
            };
            self.map.addSource("pins", {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": geojson
            });
            self.map.addLayer({
                id: "pinsLayer",
                type: "circle",
                source: "pins", 
                paint: {
                    "circle-color": "red",
                    "circle-radius": 5 
                }
            });
        });
```